# jQuery template and lazy load images

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I am using jQuery templates to add images and want to use js [lazyload()](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin for them. It says I should call `$("img.lazy").lazyload();`, so I placed it right after jtemplate adds dom, but then lazyload doesn't work. It displays a placeholder, not the images themselves. It works fine if I run it manually in firebug.

Where should I put `$("img.lazy").lazyload()` to make it work with jtemplates?

Comment: Have you tried the following?

    `$("#template").tmpl(data).appendTo(".container"); $(".container").find("img.lazy").lazyLoad()`